# Book where a boy travels to a dystopian future in which the government requires everyone to wear a tracking mini computer

Tags: story-identification, books

It was written in English, likely from the 1950s-70s. I read it as a child, and in my memory, the book is titled “The Time Machine,” but it is definitely not the H.G. Wells’ book.

The main character, a boy, travels to the future and everyone is required to keep on them a pocket calculator/PDA/computer that is connected to a government controlled centralized computer. He doesn’t have one (since he’s from the past), and so he needs to hide.

Comment: That's pretty much a trope in dystopic future sci-fi. (And in the real world too, but that's neither here nor there.) Can you remember any more details? Which country was this story set in? Was it a long novel or a short story? Where does the boy hide? What happens to him after that?

Comment: I’ve tried to add all that I could remember. I really loved the book, so I’m hoping to rediscover it. I don’t recall if it was set in a specific country, it wasn’t a short story, probably on the short-ish side of novel length. I think (and I realize this is part of the trope) most of his struggle is to get back in to his ship that was confiscated. But really the big plot point was the tracking tablet/calculator in everyone’s pocket that was illegal to be away from for more than a moment.

Comment: There were a whole series of short stories about time travel by Donald and Keith Monroe in the 1960s, and I think they were collected in an anthology just called *The Time Machine*. The protagonists were a group of boy scouts who found the time machine and had various adventures with it.

Comment: "tracking mini computer" called a smartphone in our world...

Comment: @JohnRennie Wow! I'm almost positive that's it. There's a wikipedia page with links to all the stories that I plan on checking out. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is a series of young adult stories by Donald and Keith Monroe about a group of boy scouts who find a time machine and their subsequent adventures. These are known as the [Time Machine stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_series) and were collected into two anthologies Mutiny in the Time Machine and Time Machine to the Rescue.

The stories were published between 1959 and 1989 in Boys' Life magazine so they cover the time period you mention. I don't have the collections so I can't be sure if there is a story matching the exact details you describe.